# Alternative to Regex: How to use IsLetter or IsDigit methods and specify number of letters and numbers required

Tags: c#

***I have a method like this:***

```
public static bool IsValidNumberLetter { get; set; } 

 public static void IsNumLettersInput(string checkNumberLetter)
 {
  Validated.IsValidNumberLetter = checkNumberLetter.Any(Char.IsLetter) &
  checkNumberLetter.Any(Char.IsDigit) & (checkNumberLetter.Trim().Length == 12));
 }
```

This works well except I would love to specify the number of letters the user can enter:
Example: ***1234QAZWSX***. In this example I need X amount of letters and X amount of digits, the sequence does not matter.

I do not want to use Regex.

Note: Validated is the name of the class from which I am calling the Variable ***IsValidNumberLetter***. This way I can use the Variable throughout my program for anything I need to validate for Number Letter.

Is this possible using the above method?

Thanks for your input.

Comment: Can you explain why regex is off limits? It seems like the tool *specifically* designed for this type of job. Is this just a learning exercise of some kind?

Comment: Yes, this is practice, not home work. I want to be able to use different methods. Most of the time I see people go straight for Regex. I have read several books but did not even know about some of the methods posted below by @newStackExchange.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public static bool IsValid(string source)
{
    //this will not affect the original as strings are immutable
    source = source.Trim(); 
    if (source.Length != 12) return false;
    return source.Take(4).All(char.IsLetter)
         && source.Skip(4).All(char.IsDigit);
}
```

Comment: Thanks my friend, I was able to add the Substring method, so that the first 4 characters are letters and the last 8 are numbers. This is great. Withyour example, I can play around with this. Thanks again!

Comment: @UnaverageGuy Oh right, you want the first 4 characters letters and then the next 8 digits? Fixed that.

Comment: I was my fault, should have explained better. I noticed it states ALL. But I am able to enter characters Example: !@. I can probably play around with this. Hate to drag this on.

Comment: @UnaverageGuy Just tested it, it returned false for `"!@"`.

Comment: Great, yes it works. Thank you so much!! You know we should switch screen names, my way of writing codes is way too average for an Unaverage Guy. :)
Thanks again, now I have a way to do something outside of Regex.